# Custom button with snap layouts' support

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, firemonkey, vcl

[image]

Is there any way to call "[snap layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu)" popup menu manually (for my own button)?

Comment: You may want to retag your question to get more attention. Indeed, this isn't a Delphi-specific question at all, but a pure Win32 question.

Comment: Done. BTW, I found "Win + Z" keys but I don't like it for its focus problem :-|

Comment: Like anything with *snap* in its name, there is no public API. What you *can* do, however, is responding to the `WM_NCHITTEST` message and return `HTMAXBUTTON` for your button control. I'm not sure how much this is going to break.